# Exposing promise of a wrapped function

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm creating a convenience function and I would like to return the promise of the functions promise in the form of a .then function.  Currently I have:

```
function foo(a, b){
  b = b || 'default';

  asyncBar(a + " " + b, function(err, value){
    if(err)
      console.log("oh shit");
    else
      return value;
   } 
};
```

I could add a callback argument to foo but not only is that clunky but it would remove the "convenience" from the convenience function.  I would prefer to just `foo.then(function(){...})` but I'm not sure how to pass the promise from `asyncBar()`.

UPDATE: I'm doing this in Node.js and the return call is from a random JSON-RPC library.  I would prefer to use ES6-Promises if necessary....

Comment: You want to program a `deferred` from jQuery in vanilla Javascript or what `.then()` do you mean, or does the tag `jQuery` miss?

Comment: @dollarvar jQuery is _one_ library that has a limited (and incorrect) implementation of promises. There are more serious promise libraries that offer richer, and much faster functionality like Bluebird, RSVP or Q.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thanks, I just found out, that this is even a "native" (if experimental) feature of Javascript.

Comment: @dollarvar yes :) It recently made it in! There are DOM promises in Chrome canary already and ES promises are on the way.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Wow, that didn't talk my jQuery teacher about. ;)

Comment: Since you said you're using NodeJS [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) promises are your only real viable option. They're _much much_ faster than other promise libraries (and almost as fast as callbacks, faster than the async module even). For example, when you `Promisify` with Bluebird it'll generate JavaScript code on the fly for the wrapper instead of using a closure for speed causing in a nice speedup.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum The es6-promises polyfill is working well.  I really don't need to worry about speed and I would prefer to keep library bloat down.  Thanks for your great answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) since they're the fastest you can do:

```
var bar = Promise.promisify(asyncBar);
function foo(a, b){
    return bar(a + " " + b || 'default');
}
```

Here, we're promisifying the function and then returning it. You can then do `foo.then...` - the error handling can be done in the second argument of the `.then` clause or a `.catch` clause.

If you're using another (lamer) promise library that unlike Bluebird (or Q for instance) offers this functionality out of the box - you can do:

```
//assuming broken jQuery "promises"
function foo(a, b){
  var d = $.Deferred();
  asyncBar(a + " " + b, function(err, value){
      if(err){
          d.reject();
          console.log("oh shit");
      } else {
          d.resolve(value);
      } 
   });
   return d.promise();
};
```

If we're talking about ES6 (JavaScript.next) promises, the syntax would be:

```
function foo(a, b){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        asyncBar(a + " " + b, function(err, value){
        if(err){
            console.log("oh shit");
            reject();
        } else {
            resolve(value);
        } 
   });
};
```